# When Japanese is entered with cefsharp, a child frame is displayed at the upper left

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I am writing a program incorporating cefsharp into wpf.When entering Japanese on cefsharp, the entered characters are displayed in the upper left frame as shown below. 
[image]

I want to reflect the input contents directly on the input screen. I could not fix it with cefsharp by setting the following settings.
Please tell me if anyone knows how to solve it.

```
        var browser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
        browser.BrowserSettings.AcceptLanguageList = "ja-JP";
    　　browser.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler();
.
.
.
        class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
        {
            public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
            {
                var headers = request.Headers;
                headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ja-JP,ja,en-US,en");
                request.Headers = headers;

                return CefReturnValue.Continue;
            }
    }
```

Development environment construction

-.NetFrameWork 4.6.2

-Visual studio 2017

-CefSharp v67.0.0

Comment: The `WPF` version does not support `IME` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1262

Comment: You can use the `WinForms` version hosted in `WPF` to get `IME` support.

Comment: Thank you for telling me what is impossible with WPF. I'd like to respond with winform or Eo.Webbrouser.

Comment: It's not impossible, it's just not supported yet. Use whatever browser suites your needs.